# Trim a string (tailing end) based on a specific character in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, trim

I was looking to try and figure out how trim a string in Bash, from the trailing end, once I hit a certain character.

Example: if my string is this (or any link): https://www.cnpp.usda.gov/Innovations/DataSource/MyFoodapediaData.zip

(I'll set that as my variable).
(I.e. if I `echo $var` it will return that link:)

I'm looking to use Bash, I'm guessing I will need to utilize sed or awk, but I want to trim, starting from the end until I see the first / (since the will be the file name) and strip that out.

So using that link, I'm trying to just get after the / so jus "MyFoodapediaData.zip" and set that to a different variable.

So in the end, if I echo $var2 (if I call it that) it will just return: MyFoodapediaData.zip"

I tried working with sed 's.*/" and that will start from the beginning until it finds the first slash. I was looking for the reverse order if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use bash builtin parameter substitution for this:

```
$ var='https://www.cnpp.usda.gov/Innovations/DataSource/MyFoodapediaData.zip'
$ echo "$var"
https://www.cnpp.usda.gov/Innovations/DataSource/MyFoodapediaData.zip
$ var2=${var##*/}
$ echo "$var2"
MyFoodapediaData.zip
```

`${var##*/}` means "from the beginning of the value of the `var` variable, remove everything up to the *last* slash."

See [parameter substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the manual

Comment: HOLY CRAP! You are magical.

That's amazing, it works already! Thanks for insanely fast turnaround! (Sorry it was probably such a basic question!)

Comment: No worries. We all start at zero. Keep asking questions and searching other Q&A here to soak up the knowledge